# Drupal 6 View for finding if an event is running (or starting) on a certain date

Tags: drupal, date, calendar, view

I have four Events e.g. 04/06/2011 to 08/06/2011, 04/06/2011 to 06/06/2011, 04/06/2011, and 05/06/2011.  I want to find any event that is running on say 05/06/2011 which in my example above is events 1 and 2 and 4. With Views I can enter 05/06/2011 to find Events starting on that date but I want to find Events that are running (or starting) on that date.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Better Exposed Filter module for doing this?

It sound like you should create your own views filter. Check: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/creating-custom-views-filters-exposed-form-element-drupal-6-561.html